# error when using pdo fetch assoc major error

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sqls ="SELECT * FROM review WHERE user= '{}AND id=:id";
$handle->execute($sqls);
 $result = $handle->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!(count($result) > 0)){


}
```

Guys there something wrong with this i want to check of there is something in $result and if there is nothing it should do some statements yet i get this error

Call to undefined method PDO::execute()

Comment: you also have a single quote that will break your query

Comment: Umm, im not used to PDO, but I think you have to use "prepare" before -> check this site: http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 0):

`->execute()` is for prepared statements. You want `->query()` instead.

e.g.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); // prepare the query
$stmt->execute(); // actually execute it
$row = $stmt->fetch(); // fetch data
```

and

```
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql); // directly execute the query
$row = $stmt->fetch(); // fetch data
```